# What is a combined fragment in a UML Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence

Everything is in the question. I've just discovered this new feature and I don't really understand what it stands for. All I know is that it can represent loops and alternatives in sequence diagrams.

Can someone explain me what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IBM web site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html) has an explanation of it.  To give the elevator summary - it is a way to show different conditional paths that can be taken on a sequence diagram.  There are various flavors of them, but each handles conditional flow.